# WebStorm Auto Import Does Not Resolve Packages Installed Via Another Yarn Workspace Repo

Tags: dependencies, node-modules, webstorm, yarn-workspaces

In a monorepo setup on WebStorm, I have a UI library package and an app setup as two different projects using yarn workspaces. Just as described [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44241), even though imports actually work when I add them manually, WebStorm is unable to automatically resolve imports of node-modules in the app package that have been added as dependencies in the UI package.